# How is $\sin(w_0x)+a\sin(w_1x)\cos(w_0x)=\sqrt{1+(a\sin(w_1x))^2}\sin(w_0x+\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This comes from telecomunications, Armstrongs modulator.

This
$$\sin\left(w_{0}x\right)+a\sin\left(w_{1}x\right)\cos\left(w_{0}x\right)$$
is equal to
$$\sqrt{1+\left(a\sin\left(w_{1}x\right)\right)^{2}}\sin\left(w_{0}x+\arctan\left(a\sin\left(w_{1}x\right)\right)\right)$$

I plotted them in desmos and they indeed are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is coming from the trick:

$$A\sin\theta+B\cos\theta=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\sin(\theta+\phi)$$

where

$$\cos\phi=\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}},~~~\sin\phi=\frac B{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}},~~~\tan\phi=\frac BA$$

In your case, plug in

$$A=1,~~B=a\sin\left(w_{1}x\right),~~\theta=\omega_0x,~~\phi=\arctan\left(\frac BA \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You have\begin{multline}\sin\bigl(w_0x+\arctan(a\sin(w_1x))\bigr)=\\=\sin(w_0x)\cos\bigl(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x))\bigr)+\cos(w_0x)\sin\bigl(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x))\bigr)=\\=\sin(w_0x)\frac{\sin(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))}{\tan(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))}+\\+\cos(w_0x)\tan(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))\cos(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))=\\=\sin(w_0x)\require{cancel}\color{red}{\frac{\sin(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))}{a\sin(w_1x)}}+\\+\cos(w_0x)a\sin(w_1x)\color{green}{\cos(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))}.\end{multline}So, in order to prove what you want to prove, it must be proved that both numbers$$\color{red}{\frac{\sin(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))}{a\sin(w_1x)}}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\color{green}{\cos(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))}$$are equal to$$\frac1{\sqrt{1+\left(a\sin(w_1x)\right)^2}}.$$But\begin{align}\cos(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))&=\sqrt{\cos^2(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))}\\&=\sqrt{\frac1{\sec^2(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))}}\\&=\sqrt{\frac1{1+\tan^2(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))}}\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(w_1x)}}\end{align}and\begin{align}\frac{\sin(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))}{a\sin(w_1x)}&=\cancel{\tan(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))}\frac{\cos(\arctan(a\sin(w_1x)))}{\cancel {a\sin(w_1x)}}\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(w_1x)}}.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$\begin{aligned}
\sin\left(w_{0}x\right)+a\sin\left(w_{1}x\right)\cos\left(w_{0}x\right) &= \sqrt{1+\left(a\sin\left(w_{1}x\right)\right)^{2}}(\sin(w_0x) \cos B + \sin B \cos(w_0x))\\
&= \sqrt{1+\left(a\sin\left(w_{1}x\right)\right)^{2}}(\sin(w_0x +B)
\end{aligned}$$

where

$$\begin{cases}
\cos B &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(a\sin\left(w_{1}x\right)\right)^{2}}}\\
\sin B &= \frac{a \sin(w_1x)}{\sqrt{1+\left(a\sin\left(w_{1}x\right)\right)^{2}}}
\end{cases}
$$

which gives the desired result as $\tan B = a \sin(w_1x)$.